# How to add a mp3 in scalafx gui scene?

Tags: scalafx

I trying to add a mp3 in to my scala gui using scalafx, but i have trouble how to add in to the scene

this is what i have, but it doesn't work...

```scala
val gameStage = new PrimaryStage {

  title = "Game Graphics"
  scene = new Scene(windowWidth, windowHeight) {
    var audio = new Media(url)
    var mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(audio)
    mediaPlayer.volume = 100
    mediaPlayer.play()
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Did you get an opportunity to review my answer and try out the solution? If so, and it worked for you, I would be grateful if you could mark my answer as correct by clicking the gray check mark at the top left of my answer. If not, please let me know, and I'll try to assist you further.

Comment: My bad, just new to stackoverflow...

Comment: No worries. ;-) Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that one problem is that you have not used a `MediaView` instance to add the `MediaPlayer` to the scene. Also, it's probably better if you do not start to play the media until the scene has been displayed.

I think you need something like this (as a complete app):

```scala
import scalafx.application.JFXApp
import scalafx.application.JFXApp.PrimaryStage
import scalafx.scene.{Group, Scene}
import scalafx.scene.media.{Media, MediaPlayer, MediaView}

object GameGraphics
extends JFXApp {

  // Required info. Populate as necessary...
  val url = ???
  val windowWidth = ???
  val windowHeight = ???

  // Initialize the media and media player elements.
  val audio = new Media(url)
  val mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(audio)
  mediaPlayer.volume = 100

  // The primary stage is best defined as the stage member of the application.
  stage = new PrimaryStage {

    title = "Game Graphics"
    width = windowWidth
    height = windowHeight
    scene = new Scene {

      // Create a MediaView instance of the media player, and add it to the scene. (It needs
      // to be the child of a Group, or the child of a subclass of Group).
      val mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer)
      root = new Group(mediaView)
    }

    // Now play the media.
    mediaPlayer.play()
  }
}
```

Also, you should prefer `val` to `var`, particularly if there is no need to modify the associated variables after they have been defined.

BTW, it's not possible to test your code, so please consider posting a [*minimal, complete and verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) next time.